# Oracle Apex ActiveXObject alternative for Edge data import/export text

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I use Internet explorer for my oracle apex applications but since it is not supported anymore I have to find an alternative solution to import/export data from .csv/.xls files.

I used ActiveXObject and VBA macros but it won't be possible to solve it in Microsoft Edge in that way.

For example if I want to import data from a file:

[image]

I want the "Test" button to open a certain .csv in the background and copy its content then paste it in the text area's item on the page then save it automatically.

Anyone has a proper solution?

Comment: Modern browsers won't allow you to open any files in the "background" or paste any content in a text box due to security concerns. I only see two proper solutions: Enlist your enduser to actively hit CTRL-V in your textbox, or use a file upload dialog to upload and save CSV as a lob-File, then use a parsing library like Alexandria to read the file line by line.